# How can a windows app handle ICMP requests?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, icmp, netfilter

I am trying to figure out how to handle ICMP requests on Windows.  Ideally it would be within a c++ or C# application.  If that is not possible, then how?

Essentially, I have a ping that is sending a specific Payload to my server.  Based on the contents of the payload I need to either drop or reply to the ping request.

I know it can be done on Linux using NF Queue (https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/linux/net/netfilter/nf_queue.c)

Is it possible on Windows?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  One big difference is that I actually need to handle the request.  This example just reads the request.  I don't see how to drop packets based on payload.

Comment: This might help get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx